# Python Cloud Funtion Get Requestor UID

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to get the requestor uid within a Python Cloud Function?

I am aware how to do it with Flutter sending a `httpsCallable` request and catching it in TypeScript with `...https.onCall(async (data, context) => {const uid = context.auth?.uid;})`

In Python I have the following:

```
def main(request):
try:
    print(f'request:{request}')
```

But I only get this information `request:<Request 'http://...cloudfunctions.net/' [POST]>`

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer...

```
def main(request):
 authorization = request.headers.get('Authorization')
 id_token = authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
 try:
    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
    uid = decoded_token['uid']
    print(f'uid: {uid}')
```

The following links helped me

- [Howto write a python-based firebase https function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511801/howto-write-a-python-based-firebase-https-function)
- [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web)
- [USING PYTHON DECORATORS TO AUTHENTICATE GOOGLE CLOUD FUNCTIONS](https://www.linkage.io/authorizing-google-cloud-functions-with-firebase-and-python/)